# Get all zip code using google map api which are lies in between sourece and destination pa

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a requirement to implement google map direction.User will supply source and destination.Then the full path will be shown in google map.It also show all the zip code which are lies on this path.

I dig around Google but could not found any solution to get zip code.
Please help me if you have any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the geocoder service to get the address information for your various points along your path.  The `GeocoderResults` object has an address array, which has a `postal_code` type.

Comment: It will be best if you mention the api link or reference for this service

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingAddressTypes